# Material UI DatePicker onChange not working when clicking on a day, only when changed on the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to configure a StaticDatePicker, it all works as expected, but when I try to style the days with renderDay, it no longer allows me to change the date by clicking on the day itself, and can only change the date when I click on the edit button and change the date on the input itself.

If I comment out the renderDay={(day, date, isInCurrentMonth... line, it all works normally, but the styling for each day back to the default.

Am I missing something? I tried looking into the docs, but I didn't find anything in there.

// What is being passed down as props to the component is the useState for the current selected date, and the setShow which shows/hides the calendar when a string with the date is clicked.

```
import React from 'react'
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs'
import { StaticDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { Grid, Paper, TextField } from '@mui/material'
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'


const styles = makeStyles(() => ({
  pendingCloseDay: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: '35px', 
    height: '35px',
    padding: '1px',
  },
  closedDay: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    width: '35px', 
    height: '35px',
    padding: '1px',
  },
  noMovementsDay: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: '35px', 
    height: '35px',
    padding: '1px'
  },
  currentDay: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: '35px', 
    height: '35px',
    padding: '1px'
  },
  futureDays: {
    backgroundColor: 'gray',
    width: '35px', 
    height: '35px',
    padding: '1px'
  },
  selectedDay: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    width: '35px', 
    height: '35px',
    padding: '1px'
  }
}))

const Calendar = ({date, setDate, setShow}) => {
  const classes = styles()
  const today = dayjs() 
  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setDate(e)
    setShow(prev => !prev)
  }
  
  const mockDataForDays = (day, date, isInCurrentMonth, dayComponent) => {
    let randomValueForDay = Math.random()
    const isSelected = day.$d.getDate() === date[0].$d.getDate() && day.$d.getMonth() === date[0].$d.getMonth()
    const isToday = day.$d.getDate() === today.$d.getDate() && day.$d.getMonth() === today.$d.getMonth()
    let dateTile


    if(isInCurrentMonth) {
      if(isInCurrentMonth.disabled) {
        dateTile = (
          <div key={day} className={isSelected ? classes.selectedDay : isToday ? classes.currentDay : classes.futureDays} >
            <Grid item>{day.$d.getDate()}</Grid>
          </div>
        )
      } else if(randomValueForDay >= 0.66) {
        dateTile = (
          <div key={day} className={isSelected ? classes.selectedDay : isToday ? classes.currentDay : classes.noMovementsDay} >
            <Grid item>{day.$d.getDate()}</Grid>
          </div>
        )
      } else if (randomValueForDay >= 0.33) {
        dateTile = (
          <div key={day} className={isSelected ? classes.selectedDay : isToday ? classes.currentDay : classes.closedDay} >
            <Grid item>{day.$d.getDate()}</Grid>
          </div>
        )
      } else {
        dateTile = (
          <div key={day} className={isSelected ? classes.selectedDay : isToday ? classes.currentDay : classes.pendingCloseDay} >
            <Grid item>{day.$d.getDate()}</Grid>
          </div>
        )

      }
    }
    return dateTile
  }

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <StaticDatePicker
      sx={{'.MuiDayPicker-header': {gap: '0.5rem'}}}
      // showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
      disableFuture={true}
      // closeOnSelect={true}
      openTo='day'
      value={date}
      toolbarTitle=''
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={params => <TextField  {...params} />}
      componentsProps={{
        actionBar: {
          actions: []
        }
      }}
      renderDay={(day, date, isInCurrentMonth, dayComponent) => mockDataForDays(day, date, isInCurrentMonth, dayComponent)}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}

export default Calendar
```

I'm trying to style each day, while still being able to select the date by clicking on a specific date, if someone can help me or guide me on the correct direction to solve the issue, it would be greatly appreciated :)